# Dinosaur story for children

Tags: identification-request, music

I'm hoping to identify a short dinosaur picturebook for children that would have been available by around 1994 (but was probably written earlier than that). The audiotape read-along version included music that sounded similar to [one of the themes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZYgsZPAPSs&t=180s) for the movie Inception. I unfortunately don't remember much about the plot, though I'm pretty sure it had to do with humans in some way interacting with dinosaurs -- maybe at a mechanized theme park? (I'm almost certain that the book was written long before Jurassic Park arrived.)

Comment: Do you remember anything about the illustrations?

Answer (score 2):

Could this be one of the [Dinotopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinotopia) stories? As far as I can tell, the only one of these available in 1994 would have been the first book, *Dinotopia: A Land Apart from Time*, published in 1992 - notably, before the first *Jurassic Park* film (1993) but after Michael Crichton's *Jurassic Park* novel (1990). There was also an [audiobook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1878685813) that came out in 1993.

[image: cover of the first book]

Humans interacting with dinosaurs, yes. Theme park, no: Dinotopia is an Atlantis-like island where humans and dinosaurs live together peacefully - symbiotically, even. The dinosaurs are intelligent and sapient, not monsters. Mechanised - well, the dinosaurs themselves aren't, but there's some steampunky-type machines featured in the stories:

[image: runaway]
[image: remora]

For me, these books were memorable mostly for their ***incredibly beautiful*** illustrations. If none of the pictures in this answer are ringing bells for you, then it's probably not what you're remembering (unless you only had it as an audiobook, of course, in which case you really missed out!)

[image: Will and Bix]
[image: Oriana Nascavi]

Comment: This looks like an amazing book! While I'm pretty sure it's not mine, I'm glad you shared it.

Comment: @MayorofthePlattenbaus It is an amazing book! I don't remember much about the plot, but the worldbuilding and illustrations were ***SO*** beautiful, it's a joy to read.